# How can I get log info from DB user with SQL Plus?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

we are using an Oracle database in our Company. For regulatory reasons we need a "report" with all DB users which were used to update the database of our Software in 2018 and their login and logoff timestamps. I know that Oracle has a tool which tracks that but unfortunately that feature was never used by our Company an is still deactivated. Is something like this still possible to get?

What I need should actually look like this:
1. Column: db user
2. Column: Login timestamp
3. Column: Logoff timestamp

Could be something like:

```
prod_user | 01.02.2018 05:30:05 | 01.02.2018 05:35:30  
prod_user | 02.02.2018 10:06:16 | 02.02.2018 10:48:58
```

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Unless you enable auditing in the database and audit connect, Oracle by default does not store user login/logout.

From [the `AUDIT SESSION` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/cfgaudit.htm#i1009642) :

> This option generates a single audit record for each session created by connections to an instance. An audit record is inserted into the audit trail at connect time and updated at disconnect time.  This record can include connection time, disconnection time, and logical and physical I/O processed, among other information.

For what it's worth, you can access the *last login date* of any user by looking at column `LAST_LOGIN` in administrative view `DBA_USERS`. This is a regular feature, that does not require auditing to be enabled.

Comment: Thank you. We'll use audit from now on to track those records.

Answer (score 0):

given that the user you are using has sufficient permissions you can use the DBA_AUDIT_SESSION view to check the info you need.
[Documentation Oracle 10g](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_3054.htm#i1619264)